# How do i copy files using powershell based on creation date not modification

Tags: powershell, copy

I have 2 Dirs i need to copy from one to another only specific extensions (JPG ,JPEG) only created last 24 hours 
any advise

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far. See Stack Overflow [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Something like below might work

```
Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Source\*" -Include "*.jpg","*.jpeg"|
where{!$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1))} |
Copy-Item  -Destination "C:\Destination" -Container
```

Comment: Hi , it gives bellow error PS 
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At D:\batch\stack.ps1:3 char:2
+ | <<<< Copy-Item -Destination "D:\batch\test" -Container
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement

Comment: I have corrected to code now.  I had a | on the wrong line when I pasted the code here :)

Comment: It worked thank you so much i spend over 5 days looking for this code :)